# how to choose selected option in select/option in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display two select lists with the same options (there are many).

I have the index.html:

```
<body>

<select class="c_select1"></select>
<select class="c_select2"></select>

</body>
```

and in another html file (options.html) all the options (**only** the options):

```
<option value='AED' title='United Arab Emirates Dirham'>AED</option>
<option value='AFN' title='Afghan Afghani'>AFN</option>
<option value='ALL' title='Albanian Lek'>ALL</option>
<option value='AMD' title='Armenian Dram'>AMD</option>
<option value='ANG' title='Netherlands Antillean Guilder'>ANG</option>
...
<option value='AOA' title='Angolan Kwanza'>AOA</option>
<option value='ARS' title='Argentine Peso'>ARS</option>
<option value='AUD' title='Australian Dollar'>AUD</option>
<option value='AWG' title='Aruban Florin'>AWG</option>
<option value='AZN' title='Azerbaijani Manat'>AZN</option>
```

Then, using jQuery, I load options inside the two select tags with the same instruction with different class selector:

```
 $(".c_select1").load("options.html");
```

I'd like to display as default selected option two different values (since I need to show a currency converter).

I've tried in 2 different ways, but any of these works fine (I show the code for just one).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".c_select1").load("options.html");
$(".c_select1 option[value=ARS]").prop("selected", true);
</script>
```

or

```
$(".c_select1").val("ARS");
```

I don't know why, but I think there is a problem with the .load() of jQuery.

The only solutions that work are 2:

- set a timer and execute the second jQuery statement after this timer
- use 2 different options.html files one for each select tag, but I think it is not so clever.

Is there a better way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".c_select1").load("options.html", function(){
    $(".c_select1").val("ARS");
});
```

Explained:

The `.load()` jQuery method requires some time to get the contents of `options.html` (even if its just a few milliseconds). The browser doesn't wait for it before continuing to run the rest of the javascript logic. The `function(){` I added to your `.load(` method call is some javascript logic that runs AFTER the results have returned (aka a "callback").

Answer (score 3):

Use a callback :

```
$(".c_select1").load("options.html", function() {
    $(".c_select1").val("ARS");
});
$(".c_select2").load("options.html", function() {
    $(".c_select2").val("ARS");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a delay of load method that is why selected item is not working. Like @Joulss said use callback method that should work. You can see the here.

```
 $(function(){

      $(".c_select1").load("option.html", function() {
          $(".c_select1").val("AFN");
      });

      $(".c_select2").load("option.html", function() {
          $(".c_select2").val("ANG");
      });
  });
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JgqTI12y3e7e6eBGEa1y?p=preview)